# getElementById - возвращает строку вместо объекта

Tags: css, excel, dom, vba

Постараюсь объяснить наиболее полно.
Есть табличка в экселе, есть веб-интерфейс БД.
Других возможностей, как только взаимодействовать с бд через веб - нет.
Нужно по табличным данным совершать поиск в веб интерфейсе и вытаскивать из него недостающие данные и помещать в табличку.
проблема: не могу получить объекты, что бы по ним программно "кликать"
веб интерфейс - hpsm (локальная система). версия 9.40.3006-P3
выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу щелкнуть по терминальным устройствам:

```
<div class="x-panel-header x-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable icon-micellaneous icon-hp x-accordion-hd" id="ext-gen-top115" tabindex="0" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="x-panel-header-text" id="ext-gen-top119">Терминальные устройства</span></div>
```

Делаю так:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate ("http://mos-hpsm-wb.***********/hp/index.do")
 --ожидание загрузки ---
Do While IE.Busy:  Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4:  Loop
obj = IE.Document.getElementById("ext-gen-top115") 
Do While IsNull(obj) ' это введено потому что предыдущие не отрабатывали, еще грузился контент, видимо из-за этого: "<body onload="cwc.getFrameworkWindow();cwc.setAppMode();"
Sleep (100)
obj = IE.Document.getElementById("ext-gen-top115")
'Debug.Print IsNull(obj)
Loop
'--ожидание загрузки
obj = IE.Document.getElementById("ext-gen-top115")
```

В результате в obj попадает всего лишь строковое название объекта, который я хочу использовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я получают элемент вот так (т.е. тоже самое только по имени класса):

```
obj = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("x-panel-header x-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable icon-micellaneous icon-hp x-accordion-hd")
```

То все хорошо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делаю ему: obj.Click
И свиток раскрывается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать что бы я получал элементы по ID ? Помогите пожалуйста.

п.с. то что я получил по имени классов этот объект я так понимаю "случайность" потому что мне нужно дальше "кликать" а я уже объекты не могу получить по имени классов. Вообщем нужно по ID.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Какое древнее колдунство. Код выглядит правильным, он должен вернуть элемент, могу лишь предположить неправильное приведение переменной. Может там Set retobj = IE.Document.getElementById("ext-gen-top115") попробовать, чтобы в новую переменную сохранить. Даже не знаю.

Comment: Да, вы были правы. Set obj... дело выправил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Структурирование вопроса рождает и решение. :)
Ответ:

```js
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = IE.Document.getElementById("ext-gen-top115")
obj.Click
```

Спасибо ресурсу! :)